# Create custom login widget in Wordpress with specified action address

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins

I've created a CRM system in PHP, which of course has it's own user login / admin area.  Up until this point, the index page of the top level domain would take you to a login form which I've manually created - simple username, password, forgot password sort of setup.  When the user clicks the login button, the information is sent via AJAX, PHP then processes it as necessary, returns a JSON response which tells the page what to do next - i.e. redirect to the admin page.

In short I'd like to replace the index page with an actual Wordpress website, and then have the login form somewhere within the website.  I've purchase the BeTheme theme and have activated that inside Wordpress, and it's bundled with Muffin Builder.  So far, I can see it's great for building brochure style websites but I can't seem to find anywhere the ability to add custom HTML.  Well, if I do add HTML to a page then 'input' tags are automatically stripped.

So, what I'd like to do is have a website built in wordpress, but, somewhere on one of the pages be able to integrate my own login form which has absolutely nothing to do with inbuilt wordpress users.  It uses an entirely different database on a different server.  Is this possible?

Comment: it is possible but generates a handful of complications in developement and maintenance. i suggest creating a plugin and defining your data structure in that plugin's installation script. You can then define templates from within the plugin, and even add a shortcode to integrate to an existing template! Look around a bit on plugin tutorials and if you have questions, feel free to edit here and ill follow you

Comment: Thanks Ralph, I'll take a look at plugin building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out a different way.  You can add custom HTML (including form elements) using the 'Custom HTML' widget under Appearance->Widgets.  Then, in Muffin Builder for a specific page just add 'Sidebar Widget Item' under 'Add Item', and Voila, it drops it in the page according to the usual grid system.

JS functionality can be added using Scripts n Styles plugin.